# Issue in starting/upgrading composer network: Unexpected token const

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a multi-org fabric setup which runs along with composer server. Things work quite fine normally. However, infrequently I face this issue while starting/upgrading my network:

> running start.js
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token const
>       at eval (eval at compile (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime/lib/scriptcompiler.js:99:33),
>   :3:13)
>       at ScriptCompiler.compile (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime/lib/scriptcompiler.js:99:100)
>       at Function.newInstance (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime/lib/installedbusinessnetwork.js:41:56)
>       at Function.start (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/composer.js:41:77)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

I am not able to figure out the reason due to which this issue comes. All the transaction processor functions were working just fine and there was no issue. However, out of a sudden, this issue has come.

What I have tried:

- First, I thought this was an issue with the docker images of peer and chaincode cc-env. So, I removed all my docker images related to hyperledger fabric 1.1 and downloaded them afresh. But this did not help.
- Then I removed node modules related to Hyperledger Composer and deleted entire node runtime from my system and downloaded it afresh. But this did not help either.

Versions I'm using:

- Hyperledger Fabric: 1.1
- Hyperledger Composer: 0.19.13
- Node: 8.9.4

Any references or guidance will help.

Comment: the problem is going to be in your JS scripts file. Something has been added that the compiler (scriptcompiler) doesn't like. You'll need to post the complete JS file and model so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ES6 features in your chaincode? I don't think Composer supports it.

Comment: Yes. I've used fat arrow functions at certain places. Some of them work but some of them don't.

Comment: Well, syntax error is most probably due to the fact that Composer doesn't like ES6 (but I can't tell for sure without looking at your code).

At least you can try and change const to var and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes. I reverted the syntax to ES5 for now. Specifically the arrow functions created the issue.